# Golang equivalent to Python's NotImplementedException

Tags: python, oop, go, error-handling, idioms

Is there an equivalent in Golang to raising a `NotImplementedException` in Python when you define an interface with methods that you don't want to implement yet? Is this idiomatic Golang?

For example:

```
type MyInterface interface {
    Method1() bool
    Method2() bool
}


// Implement this interface
type Thing struct {}
func (t *Thing) Method1() bool {
    return true
}

func (t *Thing) Method2() bool {
    // I don't want to implement this yet
}
```

Comment: Is it important if it is idiomatic? If it helps you, panic or log, that should be enough.

Comment: Not necessarily important, but I am still learning Go and want to understand the proper ways to use it.

Comment: I feel there's no correct answer to this. Interfaces are implemented implicitly, so if you created the interface in this case, then you should just modify it or separate into two separate interfaces. If you haven't, you should probably read the documentation and figure out how whatever uses the interface behaves and when would `Method2` be called anyway (e.g. if it's close file and you don't have a file to close, you can just do nothing and return success). In short, highly recommend that you give more information to get a better answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
func someFunc() {
   panic("someFunc not implemented")
}
```

Comment: panic() is rarely a good idea. Imagine library code doing this.

Comment: @JulianMehnle This is instead the perfect use case for panic. Why is the developer calling that function if it is just a placeholder?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example that was generated from my implementation of gRPC in Go:

```
import (
    status "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

// . . .

// UnimplementedInstanceControlServer can be embedded to have forward compatible implementations.
type UnimplementedInstanceControlServer struct {
}

func (*UnimplementedInstanceControlServer) HealthCheck(ctx context.Context, req *empty.Empty) (*HealthCheckResult, error) {
    return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unimplemented, "method HealthCheck not implemented")
}
```

Alternatively, you could log an error inside the method and then return a nil to satisfy the method contract.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common pattern in go, that you return your result or error in case of failure.

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func (t *Thing) Method2() (bool, error) {
    // I don't want to implement this yet
   return nil, errors.New("Not implemented")
   // Also return fmt.Errorf("Not implemented")
}

func (t *Thing) Method3() (bool, error) {    
   return nil, fmt.Errorf("Not implemented")
}
```

Comment: Nice solution :-) go-staticcheck is telling me that `error strings should not be capitalized (ST1005)`

Answer (score 1):

Usually in golang if you want to implement error handling you return an error

```
type MyInterface interface {
    Method1() bool
    Method2() (bool, error)
}
```

Then you can return an error.
You can also log, or panic as @coredump said in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

a empty var will do this

```
var _ MyInterface = &Thing{}
```

if `Thing` doesn't implement the interface `MyInterface`, compile will fail

Answer (score 0):

If the method must not be called (yet?) because it is not (yet?) implemented, panicing is just the right thing to do (*fail early*).

```golang
func (t *Thing) Method2() bool {
    panic("Not implemented")
}
```

You could go further and use a true `error`:

```golang
func (t *Thing) Method2() bool {
    panic(errors.New("Not implemented"))
}
```

But I don't think this is necessary because this failure is not supposed to be caught (`recover`ed) at runtime. Instead it exists just to tell the developer (s)he should use something else, so (s)he should have seen that message during early testing and fixed it.

Note that Go 1.21 has [added](https://go.dev/doc/go1.21#errorspkgerrors) [`errors.ErrUnsupported`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#ErrUnsupported) which you could also use:

```golang
func (t *Thing) Method2() bool {
    panic(errors.ErrUnsupported)
}
```